# Icon for running service

Tags: android, service, icons

I want a icon for a running service, I know that there is `android:icon`... in the services tag but I want the icon the whole in the status bar like the icon for bluetooth

Is that possible?

thanks

EDIT:

the thing with the flag and the notification is almost what I meant, its a notification which you can't delete but I meant an icon for a running service like bluetooth in the statusbar on the right of the phone not left is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create [Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) with FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT/FLAG_NO_CLEAR flag

EDIT:

[you can't change position of status bar notification icon from left to right](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ef448d3255aed91b#)(at least on devices with stock ROM)